# Need Help: New TV + Stabiliser

Tags: electrical

I really need help. I bought a 65 inch LG OLED TV 2 weeks ago. Since its an expensive TV so i bought "V Guard digi 200" from amazon, but here comes the problem. When electricity goes then it switches off my TV. My whole house is already protected under "Luminous Zelio 1100 Since Wave" inverter (but not ACs because i have taken AC off from inverter due to huge load that AC takes) so i am not sure why TV is switching off. Please help. I live in society so when electricity goes then power goes for 30 seconds before coming to society backup. Just for 30 seconds, I got Luminous inverter. which is working fine from last 2 years. But I am not sure why TV is switching off when power goes. Ideally my inverter should not let my tv to switch off. What I am missing.

I called VGuard Technicina twice. First technician said that your Inverter should be in UPS mode instead of ECO. So we tried that but that didnt work.  Today technician came and changed some card on stabiliser but moment,  power goes then it switches of my TV.  Tubelights and fans are still ON.  Please help as i am not able to figure out this

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Location detector active... Ping... Ping... *India or nearby*.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's really no way we could tell what's going wrong with your system from here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: So you have a large inverter protecting the whole house except the AC and a second unit protecting the TV? If this is true it may be an issue with the power quality to your tv unit although pure sine sometimes there are harmonics and the 2nd unit may be detecting them and shutting down.